# Oracle SQL developer error while Export Dump "DBA Privileges Required "?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, datapump

I have given grant access to my DB, but still its showing as DBA privileges required to export the Dump

Comment: Have you granted `EXP_FULL_DATABASE`  to the user running data pump?

Comment: Show us the datapump command you are using and the **exact** error message. [edit] your question, don't post additional information in comments.